# Simple repl function being compiled "out of order" with sbcl

Tags: compilation, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I have this simple program

```
(defun testing-func ()
  (print "@Repl has Started@")
  (loop (print (eval (read)))))

(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die #P"output-test"
   :toplevel #'testing-func
   :executable t)
```

Whenever I call `testing-func` in the REPL, it works correctly; like so:

```
CL-USER> (testing-func)
@Repl has Started@
1 ;;input

1 2 ;; 1 is output, 2 is input

2 3 ;; 2 is output, 3 is input

3 ;; 3 is output
```

but after compiling with `sbcl --load testing-func.lisp`, I get an output which is "out of order" with the inputs.

```
@Repl has Started@
1 ;; input
  ;; output
2 ;; input
1 ;; output
3 ;; input
2 ;; output
```

I really don't know why or how this could happen. I've also tried to get rid of the `loop` and strictly order by using recursion with use of `let*` or `funcall` but the same phenomenom occurs, which means that I have a fundemental misunderstanding about the compilation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with compilation.

Common Lisp Streams can be buffered. You need to make sure that output is reaching the user, before you let the user type in.

See the functions `FORCE-OUTPUT` and `FINISH-OUTPUT` in Common Lisp. `FINISH-OUTPUT` causes any pending output to be written to the output device and then returns.

You need to call `FINISH-OUTPUT` after the output, you want to reach the output device, is done.

```
(defun testing-func ()
  (print "@Repl has Started@")
  (print '---)
  (terpri)      
  (loop (finish-output)
        (print (eval (read)))
        (print '---)
        (terpri)))
```